# TextMate - Find & Replace Selected Text

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

In TextMate, does anyone know how you find & replace selected text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text

> 4.5.2 Find Clipboard
>
> Two useful key equivalents are ⌘E and
>   ⌘G. The first copies the selection to
>   the shared find clipboard. This works
>   in the majority of applications and
>   allows you to find the next occurrence
>   of that string by then pressing ⌘G.
>
> The find clipboard works across
>   applications so whether in Safari,
>   TextEdit, Mail, TextMate, Terminal,
>   Console, or similar, one can copy the
>   selected text to the find clipboard,
>   switch application and use ⌘G to find
>   that string.
>
> In addition TextMate offers ⇧⌘E to
>   copy the selection to the replace
>   clipboard. This is often useful to
>   save a trip to the find dialog, for
>   example if you want to replace
>   newlines with the pipe character (|)
>   for a list of items, select a newline,
>   press ⌘E to use that as the find
>   string. Now type a |, select it and
>   press ⇧⌘E so that it is copied to the
>   replace clipboard.
>
> The next step is then to either press
>   ⌃⌘F to perform the replacement in the
>   entire document, or select the range
>   in which you want the replacement to
>   occur and use ⌃⇧⌘F instead.